Can a function that's second derivative zero have a local non global maximum or min?
Is the laplacian of a scalar function in 1D equal to the second derivative of that function?
Can a Laplace equation only have a global maximum or minimum, as the value of the function is equal to the average of the function at the points near it?
Doesn't that mean that every function that has a second derivative equal to zero has a universal maximum or minimum?
(laplacian in cartasian coordinates)

You mean a function the second derivative of which is identically $=0$? In that case the  first derivative is constant and the function itself either constant (if $f^\prime = 0$) or linear (on every interval on which the function is defined).

I am asking about a general function of one unknown either x y or z and having $f''$=0

so I mean to say if that's the case can the function itself f have two different maxiumms instead of the local one found being the global

@Thomas it took me a while to connect the points yeah exactly what you are suggesting and exactly what I wanted , so we either have a line if we are looking at a segment then it can only have a global maximum or min because its continuous since it has a second derivate and in case  of a constant  indeed local = global maximum  or min, so it can either be a constant or linear ,and so it really follows Laplace  equation

I still don’t understand the question.

@Randall I was unaware it is  intuitive , i had tried to understand if there is really a connection between laplacian and second order derivative for one unknown since when I wrote them I got the same formula , and mainly my question was about Laplace equation and second order derivative I remember a lot of cases were second order derivative is zero but we have a maximum there like x^4  , yet I don't remember if there was a case of 2 maximums , I know for a fact when Laplace is zero there is only a universal maximum or minimum and there can't be a local one that's not the maximum

yet I forgot that I was not taking the Laplacian on a point for this to happen  instead on the whole function so the second derivative would be identically zero

my thought process second derivative was not identically zero and have to have just a universal maximum or min, and if that would be right to wrong , and that why you see me trying to explain to Thomas my intention and then realising he gave me the answer this is right just in case its identically zero not at a certain point

@Jake I do thank you for clearing up the question, much better phrased learnt a lot
